# Как запустить один браузер для нескольких тестов в разных файлах Python/pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Только начинаю развиваться в автоматизированном тестировании. Нужна помощь более опытных коллег)
Пишу автотесты под проект, есть несколько файлов .py, в каждом из которых один автотест (выполняющий проверку определенного функционала). Можно ли каким-то образом инициализировать и запустить браузер ОДИН раз для всех имеющихся файлов? Чтобы я к примеру через терминал запустил тесты из одной папки и они все выполнились в одной сессии браузера? То есть не закрывать браузер после выполнения каждого файла с кодом автотеста, а запустить один браузер и сделать так, чтобы он просто брал разные ссылки, указанные в коде через browser.get("")? Заранее всех благодарю за ответы.
Есть файл, в котором создал вот такую фикстуру:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from m1.config.local_config import *
import time
from Credentials.credentials_magento import *

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get(magento_base_url)
    name = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    name.send_keys(user_name)
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
    password.send_keys(user_password)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("action-login")
    button.click()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

UPD: По совету Roman Konoval исправил код, но проблема все равно не решена. У меня все равно для каждого файла инициализируется новый браузер хром, правда теперь старый не закрывается) А можно ли сделать так, чтобы браузер инициализировался один раз и все, пока не откроется каждый файл и не пройдут нужные в нем тесты, он вообще больше не инициализировался. А сейчас получается так, что описанный выше код все равно перед запуском каждого файла (а в каждом файле у меня хранится код одного тест кейса для лучшей читабельности) открывает новый браузер и выполняет код из фикстуры. Как сделать так, чтобы этот код из фикстуры выполнился ОДИН раз, при запуске любого теста и все, больше не выполнялся, пока не закроется браузер?
Теперь код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from m1.config.local_config import *
import time
from Credentials.credentials_magento import *

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def browser():
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get(magento_base_url)
        name = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        name.send_keys(user_name)
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
        password.send_keys(user_password)
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("action-login")
        button.click()
        yield driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб получить то поведение, что вам нужно, укажите для фикстуры `scope='session'` и используйте ее во всех тестах.

В этом случае она будет создана один раз до конца прогона тестов. А значит и браузер будет создан один раз.

Учтите только, что сейчас у вас в коде есть потенциальная проблема с закрытием  сессии. Если тест закончится с ошибкой, то сессия не будет удалена (и браузер не закроется). Что гарантированно все закрыть нужно делать так:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def browser():
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get(magento_base_url)
        name = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        name.send_keys(user_name)
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("login")
        password.send_keys(user_password)
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("action-login")
        button.click()
        yield driver
```